# Load a specific controller in didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I'm developing `push notification` on my app. I want that when people tap on push message, app open a specific controller;

If I do that with:

```
storyBoardName = @"MyStoryboardName";
UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyBoardName bundle:nil];
MainWebController* MainWeb = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainWeb"];
MainWeb.urlToLoad = URL_TO_LOAD;
self.window.rootViewController = MainWeb;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

works, I can see `MainWeb` when i tap on push massage but the controller view cover all the screen: tab bar and navigation bar are hided!

I know that `rootviewcontroller` is a `uitabbar`:

```
 NSLog(@"Controller: %@",self.window.rootViewController.debugDescription);
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved with:

```
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

tabController.selectedIndex = 0;

UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)tabController.selectedViewController;
[navigationController pushViewController:MainWeb animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the `rootViewController` by setting it to be a `MainWebController`. Is this the initial `UIViewController` in your `Storyboard`?

From your issue it would seem that the initial `UIViewConroller` is a `TabViewController` and what you actually want is to setup a `UIViewController` inside this.

Comment: so, how can I do that?